# Proving that the set of permutations is a group

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a set. Then Perm$(X)$ is a group with $\mathbb{1}=id_X$ and function composition as the operation. Perm$(X)$ is the set of permutations of $X$.

I am not very sure how to go about doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You need to show that

- $\circ:\operatorname{Perm}(X)\times \operatorname{Perm}(X)\to \operatorname{Perm}(X)$ is well-defined, that is, that the composition of two permutations on $X$ is a permutation on $X$
- $\circ$ is associative, that is, for all $f,g,h\in\operatorname{Perm}(X)$ we have
  $$
  (f\circ g)\circ h = f\circ(g\circ h)
  $$
- The identity element is $id_X$, that is, for all $f\in\operatorname{Perm}(X)$ we have
  $$
  f\circ id_X = id_X\circ f=f
  $$
- Every $f\in \operatorname{Perm}(X)$ has an inverse, that is, for all $f\in \operatorname{Perm}(X)$ there exists $g\in\operatorname{Perm}(X)$ such that
  $$
  f\circ g = g\circ f = id_X
  $$